# How to stop deferred emails

Tags: postfix

I have a Postfix mail gateway.  At the same time, every other host is set to use this gateway as the relay.

We have some automated outgoing emails sent from some hosts.  I believe the gateway tries to send a deferred status back to the system started this. But that system is a null client, which sends but not receive any email

Is there anyway to stop sending the deferred status?

Example log output:

> postfix/smtp[35725]: 2F6A155C256: to=, relay=none, delay=260862, delays=260862/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to orange.mydom.com[192.168.1.5]:25: Connection refused)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Deferred" means that Postfix tried to deliver the message but failed (in this case because the MX server rejected the SMTP connection), and so it is going to wait a while and try to deliver it later. Postfix isn't sending a status report, it is simply trying to deliver a message which it was asked to deliver. That message may have been generated by Postfix (e.g. a bounce notification regarding the failed deliver of a different message), or it may have been generated by another client altogether. You need to figure out where that message came from, and fix whatever is generating it to either not generate it, or to send it elsewhere.

Comment: It should be mentioned that when a mail is deferred, it is stored for later retry until a maximum amount of time has passed.

Comment: A good guide on how to control how much time an email is stored / when delivery is retried is available here https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/mail_systems/postfix_documentation/TUNING_README_008.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a mail in your server's mail queue that goes to an email address that you helpfully edited out of your quoted syslog line. It's been there for a while.

You'll have to figure out what process is generating those emails and fix it at the source. It might be a matter of editing /etc/mailname on the other hosts, or telling your gateway host to consider mail from the other hosts as local and deliver it locally rather than attempting to send it back to the originating system.

There is no "send a deferred status back to the system" mechanism in SMTP to requeue a mail at the originator server after the SMTP connection has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command to stop sending deferred emails.

```
postsuper -d ALL deferred
```